# How do I handle ngIf fields in HTML with python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using the following line from beuatifulSoup to extract a section of javascript generated HTML:

```
soup.find('span',{'class':'price-unit ng-binding'})
```

to get:

```
<span class="price-unit ng-binding" ng-class="{wanted: ad.wanted}">
<!-- ngIf: ad.price && ad.price !== '' --><span class="currency ng-binding ng-scope" 
ng-if="ad.price &amp;&amp; ad.price !== ''">
</span><!-- end ngIf: ad.price && ad.price !== '' -->2,350
        <!-- ngIf: !ad.price || ad.price === '' -->
```

However I want to extract the value **2350** from above.

Is it possible to use findall to drill down further or do I need to strip the value out manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the `.text` along with `strip()` to get the output you want.

```
>>> soup.find('span',{'class':'price-unit ng-binding'}).text.strip()
u'2,350'
```